# Some non-english alphabets are missing after compilation

Tags: pdftex, babel

There are some non-English alphabets in my document, and these alphabets displays well in my Emacs (Ubuntu). But after i compiled using pdflatex, these alphabets are missing. I tried in the Window, and the result is the same.

My document is like:

```
\usepackage[english, french, german]{babel}

    André
```

I tried several ways, but the last alphabet always miss. What package should i use? Thanks

Comment: Are you loading `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`?

Comment: @Sigur Please, add an answer (and ping me when you do it)

Comment: @egreg, sorry for being late. I'm too busy this semester.

Answer (score 1):

Load the package `inputenc` with the correct option using

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

Other common option is `latin1` (ending with number one, not letter l). This is for ISO files.